# RNCryptor vector Test Android JNI

Tags: android-ndk, cryptography, java-native-interface, android-testing, rncryptor

Hello i've ported RNCryptor to Android [Library](https://github.com/TGIO/RNCryptorNative). I have to run this against the [test vectors](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-Spec/tree/master/vectors/v3). But i don't know how to do it.

**Can i get an example or explanation about this type of test? I'm not asking code, but the pattern. What i have to test, what to expect in test result, what cases to test & etc.**

Comment: What do you mean by " i've ported RNCryptor to Android" since is already an [implementation](https://github.com/RNCryptor/JNCryptor) that runs on Android.

Comment: JNCryptor isn't an android implementation, "runs" doesn't mean that its made for android, most obvious reason is perfomance. Check benchmark [results](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TGIO/RNCryptorNative/master/screenshots/25.png)

Comment: Please, why is your version faster and for the `results` what was the data size?

Comment: my version is faster because the cryptography code runs in native mode, C/C++ via JavaNativeBridge. Data size is string with 200 symbols (a-z+0-9)

Comment: Do I understand that encrypting 200 bytes with RNCryptor took 10.1 seconds and with RNCryptorNative 1.2 seconds? That is really to slow in both cases. What is taking all the time, is it password extension, that is supposed to be slow. Test on some larger sizes such as 100K bytes. By comparison just encrypting on an iPhone6 runs at about 400MB/s. There is something else going on here.

Comment: ah my bad, the results shown in [this screenshot](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TGIO/RNCryptorNative/master/screenshots/25.png) shows 25 runs for 200 symbol strings, [the second one](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TGIO/RNCryptorNative/master/screenshots/1.png) shows for only 1 run. And the comparison is between RNCryptorNative and JNCryptor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113161/discussion-between-tgio-and-zaph).

Comment: Still, 124ms/200 bytes is very slow, that is only 1,600-bytes/s. There is something wrong, either in the benchmarking or the code.

Comment: Well, thats good point, it seems really slow compared to 400MB/s. I will investigate this. Meanwhile, could you help with the question about vector tests?

Comment: Note iPhone has hardware encryption but newer/high-end Android phones should be close.

Comment: Anyway, if have a faster implementation, instead of forking contact Rob to get it into the RNCryptor release.

Comment: Rob is already informed about my library. He is waiting for me to finish vector test thingies, thats why i asked question about vector tests :)

Comment: @zaph, OP and I are already in discussion about the vectors, etc. He's completely right that the Java version (JNCryptor) is unusably slow on Android. It's a long-known problem. You can't judge the performance over small messages, though. Tens of ms are spent just generating the keys due to PBKDF2. On an iPhone 4, I designed key generation to take around 160ms (I actually designed it to take 80ms, but I forgot that was doing it twice…), so 124ms isn't surprising.

Comment: Yes, I was getting at testing larger sizes and determining where the performance issues are.

Comment: But doesn't JNCryptor have test vectors / JUnit tests that would be enough to test the Android version? You may just have to add some boundary cases.